# How to catch iframe POST data on the parent webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage with an iframe :

```
<iframe id="foo" src="foo.html"></iframe>
```

This iframe hosts an hidden form (foo.html) which is submitted to an external page on another domain (http://example.com/foobar) :

```
<form name="foobar" action="http://example.com/foobar" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="returnURL" value="bar.html">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.foobar.submit();
</script>
```

The external webpage consists of a series of forms.  On its final form, the validation submits POST data to the URL set in `returnURL`.

From the user point of view, what happens currently is that the browser is redirected to `returnURL`.  This is not what I want.

What I need is to treat the POST data within the original webpage, without it being refreshed.

I can think of a few options :

- triggering on the iframe POST exit and catch POST data ;
- setting `returnURL` to the original webpage and handle the POST data without reloading the page ;
- setting `returnURL` to another webpage and update the current page when it receives the POST data.

Unfortunately I don't seem able to implement any of these.  What would be the best option, and where should I start ?

Use of jQuery is allowed.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the result of the form submission to fill the full page, not just sit in the iframe?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not really, I want to close the iframe and process data on the original webpage, but I don't want the result of the form submission to replace everything.  I just want to process the form data (as is already done through ajax with local forms on the same page).  I hope it's clearer…

Comment: You have access of both domain? Can you able to change on both server?

Comment: @Mitul : No, I can't do anything on the second domain (only have HTTP client access).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are on different domains, security restrictions in javascript will prevent you from communicating between the two frames.

Comment: Right, but as mentioned in the question the POST data is sent from the external iframe to a local URL.